# Using CAPM to find the price of an option

Tags: option-pricing, capm

I was reading a textbook about finding the price of an option on a one-period binomial model.
The textbook way of doing it is to replicate the option with cash and stock for $t=T$, and then calculate the portfolio value at $t=0$.

For example:
$r=0.1, s=10, u=1.2, d=0.7, p_u=0.2,p_d=0.8$

we want to find the price of a call option with strike $K=9$

we can replicate this option with $x$ units of cash and $y$ units of stock.
we get:

$x(1+r)+yS_u=(S_u-K)^+, x(1+r)+yS_d=(S_d-K)^+$

plug in numbers, we get:

$1.1x+12y=3, 1.1x+7y=0$

solution is: $y=\frac{3}{5}, x=\frac{21}{5.5}$

portfolio value at $t=0$ is $x+ys=\frac{12}{5.5}$

if we use CAPM to solve this problem, we firstly find the market return (treat the stock as the market) $\mu_m$ and market variance $\sigma_m^2$

Let the call option price at $t=0$ be $c$

$\mu_m=s(p_uu+p_dd)-s=10(1.2*0.2+0.8*0.7)-10=-2$

$\sigma_m^2=p_u(s(u-1)-\mu_m)^2+p_d(s(d-1)-\mu_m)^2=0.2*(2-(-2))^2+0.8*(-3-(-2))^2=3.2+0.8=4$

Now calculate the covariance of market and call option $cov_{m,c}$

firstly calculate the average return of the option $\mu_c$:

$\mu_c=p_u(su-K)^++p_d(sd-K)^+-c=0.2(12-9)+0.8*0-c=0.6-c$

and then

$cov_{m,c}=p_u(s(u-1)-\mu_m)((su-K)^+-c-\mu_c)+p_d(s(d-1)-\mu_m)((sd-K)^+-c-\mu_c)
=0.2(2-(-2))((3-c)-(0.6-c))+0.8(-3-(-2))(0-c-(0.6-c))=0.2*4*2.4+0.8*(-1)*(-0.6)=2.4$

we get $\beta=\frac{cov_{m,c}}{\sigma_m^2}=0.6$

now use CAPM formula we get:

$\mu_c=rc+\beta(\mu_m-rs)$ which is:

$0.6-c=0.1c+0.6(-2-0.1*10)$

solve for $c$ and we get

$c=\frac{12}{5.5}$

So we get the same result using CAPM.

Comment: Nice! Where / what is your question though? Btw, David Shimko recently wrote something about this topic in the Journal of Derivatives.

Comment: The original Black Scholes paper from 1971 derived the BS formula in two ways (1) From the CAPM and (2) From the dynamic hedging argument. However there is little interest nowadays in the CAPM based argument, it is of historical interest only, The second method is preferred. (IMHO you can ignore the first).

Comment: So basically nothing can have a higher sharpe ratio than the market, and any asset's sharpe ratio is market's sharpe ratio multiply by it's correlation coefficient with the market.

Comment: I remember Marc Kritzman wrote a detailled example and the reasoning why those models coincide in "Puzzles in Finance".  As mentioned before, BS is favoursed as no assumption on risk premia and preferences is needed. So.. whats your question?